# Android 4.4 intelligent standby (eclipse android app)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I know that on galaxy tab 3 10'' with android 4.4 or maybe also with android 4.3 is possible to enable the intelligent standby that works with face recognition (i think). I'd like to know that is possible to call the native method of this feature on eclipse to create an android app.

Comment: Are you asking about just face detection? Check the documentation for the Camera http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: No, i'm asking about this specific feature because i already tried to use face detection methods and they aren't what i'm searching for

Comment: So to understand it correctly, you want your app to recognize a face whenever it is open, and react to it?

Comment: yes, exactly, i want to do something like this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: nope, i already tried these methods, i'd like to use the new feature used on the galaxy tab for example to enable the intelligent standby, i don't know if u ever tried it and i even don't know if is possible using a native method to use this feauture on eclipse

Comment: edit: the android feauture is called smart pause and not intelligent standby